# jquery: tooltip is not displaying data after space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I am trying to show on mouse hover event data using jquery tool tip. have data like this way:
`{"description":"marry christmas","date":"2016-12-25`"}` that I got from server as JSON string. I am parsing that on my calendar like this way
holi is a variable name that holds above JSON string
this is my import

```
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



   $.each(JSON.parse(holi), function(i, item) {
        var holidayDate=item.date+"";
       var parts= holidayDate.split("-");
       alert("parts:"+parts[2]);
       document.getElementById(parts[2]+parts[1]).style.color="green";
      var va= document.getElementById(parts[2]+parts[1]).innerHTML;
       document.getElementById(parts[2]+parts[1]).innerHTML="<label id="+parts[2]+parts[1]+" title="+
       item.description+">"+va+"</label>";
       $("#"+parts[2]+parts[1]).tooltip();

    });
    }
```

Now when I hover on 25th December it is just showing me marry instead of "marry christamas" I tried this in chrome. please let me what's wrong in this??

Comment: First of all, why don't you use jQuery for getting DOM elements? Secondy: try to put the description inside a `title` attribute.

Comment: Your code looks like it finds an element by some id value, and then tries to add another element inside it with the *same* id value. That's an error: id values have to be unique across the DOM.

Comment: first I found convenient get DOM elements using java script and 2nd I tried that way but its the same result. just giving me 1st part

Comment: @Pointy:then how should I do it? because I got all variable at runtime. I tried by removing **id="+parts[2]+parts[1]+" ** in label part. but then it is not showing any tooltip on that element because it overwrites it

Comment: Why does the `<label>` need an id of it's own anyway? You can always find it by the parent element's id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When constructing the title HTML, you need to take into account how the HTML will be parsed. If your title message has spaces, then the HTML attribute value has to be quoted.

You could clean up your code a lot by leveraging the jQuery APIs, since you're already using the library:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(holi), function(i, item) {
  var holidayDate = item.date + "";
  var parts = holidayDate.split("-");
  var dayId = parts[2] + parts[1], day = $("#" + dayId);

  day.css("color", "green")
      .html($("<label/>", {
        title: item.description,
        html: day.html()
      }))
      .find("label").tooltip();

});
```

With jQuery, you can construct new HTML with less ugly quote-wrangling by using the form

```
$("<tagname/>" {
  attribute: value,
  attribute: value,
  // ...
})
```

In this case, the code sets the "title" attribute and then the content; the "html" attribute works like the jQuery `.html()` method.

After that, it finds the just-added `<label>` element and invokes the `.tooltip()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes around the title attribute value. Try this:

```
document.getElementById(parts[2]+parts[1]).innerHTML
="<label id="+parts[2]+parts[1]+" title='"+item.description+"'>"+va+"</label>";
```

Notice the single quotes after the = and before the > around your item.description variable.

Also, as others have pointed out, avoid writing out the DOM from javascript. It is error prone and hard to maintain.